# How can I remove the red dashed lines of the cursor in Praat?

Tags: prosody, praat

I am writing a conference paper where I want to include the PRAAT analyses of some spoken sentences (I will use screenshots), but I cannot get rid of the red cursor lines. Is there a way to deactivate the cursor?

Comment: There is no way to remove the cursor (you could place it at the very beginning or very end of the file and then zoom in a bit), but I think the graphical result of taking screenshots is not that aesthetically pleasing, so I'd rather suggest to create custom pictures in Praat rather than screenshots.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is primarily about using a certain software, not about the phenomenons taking place in languages itself.

Comment: As far as I know, screenshots are officially disapproved of, and you are supposed to use the painting / drawing objects.